# How to document a method with parameter(s)?

Tags: python, documentation, documentation-generation

How to document methods with parameters using Python's documentation strings?

[PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) gives this example:

```
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)

    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0: return complex_zero
    ...
```

Is this the convention used by most Python developers?

```
Keyword arguments:
<parameter name> -- Definition (default value if any)
```

I was expecting something a little bit more formal such as

```
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    @param: real The real part (default 0.0)
    @param: imag The imaginary part (default 0.0)

    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0: return complex_zero
    ...
```

Environment: Python 2.7.1

Comment: Have you read PEP 257? http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Comment: There are several 'standards' out there but on a practical approach and especially if you like something formal, I would recommend [sphinx](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html). Its integration in [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) makes generating well structured docstrings rather painless. IMHO

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Based on my experience, the [numpy docstring conventions](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard) (PEP257 superset) are the most widely-spread *followed* conventions that are also supported by tools, such as [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).

One example:

```
Parameters
----------
x : type
    Description of parameter `x`.
```

Comment: This is closer to what I expected. Unfortunately, I picked plain PEP 257 and added my own convention (at the cost of loosing autogenerated HTML/PDF documentation).

However, next time, I will pick this solution. Thanks.

Comment: When I attempt processing your suggested docstring, Sphinx complains `SEVERE: Unexpected section title` — do you know any way to make Sphinx happier about it?

Comment: @BrandonRhodes this links talks about using these conventions with Sphinx: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt

Comment: This may have been the best answer at the time the question was asked, but I think as of now (late 2017), Sphinx has emerged victorious.

Comment: The link in @BrandonRhodes comment is now broken. Now here: https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard

Answer (score 280):

Since docstrings are free-form, it really depends on what you use to parse code to generate API documentation.

I would recommend getting familiar with the [Sphinx markup](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#python-signatures), since it is widely used and is becoming the de-facto standard for documenting Python projects, in part because of the excellent [readthedocs.org](https://readthedocs.org) service. To [paraphrase an example](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists) from the Sphinx documentation as a Python snippet:

```
def send_message(sender, recipient, message_body, priority=1) -> int:
   """
   Send a message to a recipient.

   :param str sender: The person sending the message
   :param str recipient: The recipient of the message
   :param str message_body: The body of the message
   :param priority: The priority of the message, can be a number 1-5
   :type priority: integer or None
   :return: the message id
   :rtype: int
   :raises ValueError: if the message_body exceeds 160 characters
   :raises TypeError: if the message_body is not a basestring
   """
```

This markup supports [cross-referencing](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.8/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) between documents and more. Note that the Sphinx documentation uses (e.g.) `:py:attr:` whereas you can just use `:attr:` when documenting from the source code.

Naturally, there are other tools to document APIs. There's the more classic [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) which uses `\param` [commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) but those are not specifically designed to document Python code like Sphinx is.

Note that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334531/using-javadoc-for-python-documentation) with a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339352/1174784) in here...

Comment: This is the style used by PyCharm's comment autogeneration by default

Comment: What about the syntax of composite types like lists of stuff?

Comment: then it's a `list`.

Comment: I don't know why they don't recommend putting empty line between each parameter-type pair. This is so ugly.

Comment: @Ereghard being compact is always better, you will get used to it over time.

Comment: Please update for use of type hints. Can Sphinx grab the type hint from the parameter declaration (e.g., `sender: str`) so the type does not have to be repeated on the `:param sender` line?

Comment: I definitely don't know why they _would_ recommend an empty line between parameter lines, @Ereghard. It would get _very_ long, very fast, and it's not recommended either in another major language called PHP - which, IIRC, inherits its PHPDoc syntax from JavaDoc. Not to mention, params actually work as a block on itself, usually getting separate from the description and, sometimes, from the return and throw/raise tags.

Answer (score 40):

Conventions:

- [PEP 257 Docstring Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)
- [PEP 287 reStructuredText Docstring Format](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/)

Tools:

- [Epydoc: Automatic API Documentation Generation for Python](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/)
- [sphinx.ext.autodoc – Include documentation from docstrings](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html)
- [PyCharm has some nice support for docstrings](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/generating-reference-documentation.html)

---

Update: Since Python 3.5 you can use [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) which is a compact, machine-readable syntax:

```
from typing import Dict, Union

def foo(i: int, d: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]) -> int:
    """
    Explanation: this function takes two arguments: `i` and `d`.
    `i` is annotated simply as `int`. `d` is a dictionary with `str` keys
    and values that can be either `str` or `int`.

    The return type is `int`.

    """
```

The main advantage of this syntax is that it is defined by the language and that it's unambiguous, so tools like PyCharm can easily take advantage from it.

Comment: Although this answer is now the most upvoted, neither of the PEPs above provides a convention to specify the types of arguments of a method.

Answer (score 12):

python doc strings are **free-form**, you can document it in any way you like.

Examples:

```
def mymethod(self, foo, bars):
    """
    Does neat stuff!
    Parameters:
      foo - a foo of type FooType to bar with.
      bars - The list of bars
    """
```

Now, there are some conventions, but python doesn't enforce any of them. Some projects have their own conventions. Some tools to work with docstrings also follow specific conventions.

Answer (score 8):

If you plan to use Sphinx to document your code, it is capable of producing nicely formatted HTML docs for your parameters with their 'signatures' feature.  http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#signatures

Answer (score 5):

The mainstream is, as other answers here already pointed out, probably going with the [Sphinx way](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#signatures) so that you can use Sphinx to generate those fancy documents later.

That being said, I personally go with inline comment style occasionally.

```
def complex(  # Form a complex number
        real=0.0,  # the real part (default 0.0)
        imag=0.0  # the imaginary part (default 0.0)
        ):  # Returns a complex number.
    """Form a complex number.

    I may still use the mainstream docstring notation,
    if I foresee a need to use some other tools
    to generate an HTML online doc later
    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0:
        return complex_zero
    other_code()
```

One more example here, with some tiny details documented inline:

```
def foo(  # Note that how I use the parenthesis rather than backslash "\"
          # to natually break the function definition into multiple lines.
        a_very_long_parameter_name,
            # The "inline" text does not really have to be at same line,
            # when your parameter name is very long.
            # Besides, you can use this way to have multiple lines doc too.
            # The one extra level indentation here natually matches the
            # original Python indentation style.
            #
            # This parameter represents blah blah
            # blah blah
            # blah blah
        param_b,  # Some description about parameter B.
            # Some more description about parameter B.
            # As you probably noticed, the vertical alignment of pound sign
            # is less a concern IMHO, as long as your docs are intuitively
            # readable.
        last_param,  # As a side note, you can use an optional comma for
                     # your last parameter, as you can do in multi-line list
                     # or dict declaration.
        ):  # So this ending parenthesis occupying its own line provides a
            # perfect chance to use inline doc to document the return value,
            # despite of its unhappy face appearance. :)
    pass
```

The benefits (as @mark-horvath already pointed out in another comment) are:

- Most importantly, parameters and their doc always stay together, which brings the following benefits:
- Less typing (no need to repeat variable name)
- Easier maintenance upon changing/removing variable. There will never be some orphan parameter doc paragraph after you rename some parameter.
- and easier to find missing comment.

Now, some may think this style looks "ugly". But I would say "ugly" is a subjective word. A more neutual way is to say, this style is not mainstream so it may look less familiar to you, thus less comfortable. Again, "comfortable" is also a subjective word. But the point is, all the benefits described above are objective. You can not achieve them if you follow the standard way.

Hopefully some day in the future, there will be a doc generator tool which can also consume such inline style. That will drive the adoption.

PS: This answer is derived from my own preference of using inline comments whenever I see fit. I use the [same inline style to document a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13761377/728675) too.

Comment: I think this a neat way to do it.  A big advantage is that the parameter and its doc are in the same place, which is helpful if you refactor things/change type annotations etc - you don't need to keep two different lists of stuff in sync. I hope a doc generator tool for doing it this way gets built!

Comment: I personally like this style, however my IDE doesn't show these comment in tooltips/autocomplete :(

Answer (score 4):

**Sphinx Python 3 typing minimal runnable example**

Just to make what other answers said more concrete:

build.sh

```
sphinx-build . out
```

conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = [ 'sphinx.ext.autodoc' ]
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
    'show-inheritance': True,
}
autodoc_typehints = "description"
```

index.rst

```
.. automodule:: main
```

main.py

```
class MyClass:
    """
    This class does that.
    """
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

def do_this(parameter1: int, parameter2: MyClass) -> int:
   """
   This function does this.

   :param parameter1: my favorite int
   :param parameter2: my favorite class
   :return: what it returns
   """
   return parameter1 + parameter2.i
```

requirements.txt

```
Sphinx==6.1.3
```

Output on `out/index.html`:

[image]

If we remove:

```
autodoc_typehints = "description"
```

typing types show on the function signature instead:

[image]

**Pre-typing equivalent**

The following produces the same output as the version with `autodoc_typehints = "description"`, but with a bit more parameter name repetition:

```
def do_this(parameter1, parameter2):
   """
   This function does this.

   :param parameter1: my favorite int
   :type parameter1: int
   :param parameter2: my favorite class
   :type parameter2: MyClass
   :return: what it returns
   :rtype: int
   """
   return parameter1 + parameter2.i
```

**The dream: argument docstrings**

It is bad that we have to retype argument names for every `:param argumentname:`. There doesn't seem to be a good solution to this currently. Some ways it might be solved in the future:

- Sphinx could add `#:` doc comments to parameters. This Sphinx extension already works for instance attributes as mentioned at: [How to show instance attributes in sphinx doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649105/how-to-show-instance-attributes-in-sphinx-doc)

  ```
  class MyClass:
      def __init__(self, par1: int):
          #: My favorite attribute!
          self.var1: int = par1
  ```

  so why not give us:

  ```
  def do_this(
      #: my favorite int
      parameter1: int,
      #: my favorite class
      parameter2: MyClass
  ) -> int:
  ```
- Python could finally actually support argument docstrings natively!

  ```
  def do_this(
      parameter1: int,
      """
      my favorite int
      """

      parameter2: MyClass
      """
      my favorite class
      """
  ) -> int:
  ```

TODO find feature requests for these!

Same desire also mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581355/895245

**Other useful typing related things to know**

- how to represent multiple types: [How to express multiple types for a single parameter or a return value in docstrings that are processed by Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647966/how-to-express-multiple-types-for-a-single-parameter-or-a-return-value-in-docstr)
- how to link to the documentation of types of external projects: [Specifying targets for intersphinx links to numpy, scipy, and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538983/specifying-targets-for-intersphinx-links-to-numpy-scipy-and-matplotlib)

Tested on Python 3.10, Ubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score 3):

Building upon the type-hints answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9195565/2418922), which provides a better structured way to document types of parameters, there exist also a structured manner to document both type and descriptions of parameters:

```
def copy_net(
    infile: (str, 'The name of the file to send'),
    host: (str, 'The host to send the file to'),
    port: (int, 'The port to connect to')):

    pass
```

example adopted from: https://pypi.org/project/autocommand/

Comment: Is this an official syntax? Its super useful, however I can't find it in the official docs/PEPs...

Comment: I'd like to know that too, if there is a PEP for it.

Comment: This seems like it would mean "a tuple of two elements: a string and a literal string, a typing.Literal, with text "The name of the file to send"' -- this is also how pyright is interpreting it. While possibly nice, unless a PEP is explicitly adopted to allow this in the future, I don't think this is the right answer.

Answer (score -3):

Docstrings are only useful within interactive environments, e.g. the Python shell. When documenting objects that are not going to be used interactively (e.g. internal objects, framework callbacks), you might as well use regular comments. Here’s a style I use for hanging indented comments off items, each on their own line, so you know that the comment is applying to:

```
def Recomputate \
  (
    TheRotaryGyrator,
      # the rotary gyrator to operate on
    Computrons,
      # the computrons to perform the recomputation with
    Forthwith,
      # whether to recomputate forthwith or at one's leisure
  ) :
  # recomputates the specified rotary gyrator with
  # the desired computrons.
  ...
#end Recomputate
```

You can’t do this sort of thing with docstrings.

Comment: Ugly yes?  Interesting idea... also yes.

Comment: Inline comments for the variables is very sensible, less typing (no need to repeat variable name), easier maintenance upon changing/removing variable... easier to find missing comment. Would combine it with proper docstring below the signature. +1

Comment: That doesn't work as documentation. If you comment your package like this and a PyCharm user downloads it, they won't be able to check what each param does without accessing your documentation - which you won't be able to generate  with any software. Unless you make your own. That's why OP asks for specifying it in docstring. Sorry so late.

Comment: This is just awful.