# Docstring - Usage of parameter name and type of in python

Tags: python, docstring

I've written some classes in Python and I have written docstrings for them like this:

```
class DB:
    def execute_and_return(self, sql):
        """Execute the query and returns the result as a list of list
        Parameters
        ----------
        sql: str
            Your query
        Returns
        -------
        list""
```

If I want to access the docstring in another class I can simply call `DB.execute_and_return.__doc__` and I get the string.

However if I'm interesting to know the name of the parameters (in this case `sql`) and the type of data (in this case `str`) is there any built in functions for accessing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to document a method with parameter(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195455/how-to-document-a-method-with-parameters)

Comment: its not asking how to document it's asking how to find the real function definition

Answer (score 0):

python does not have strict types, so you can never be sure of what type a variable should be unless it is clearly stated in the documentation. but there is a way to find the variable names in python:

```
import inspect
args = inspect.getargspec(DB.execute_and_return)[0]
```