# How to add context comments to functions in Pythons

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, comments

I've tried searching this online, however as I don't know the actual term for them I struggled to find anything of use.
If  i am to create my own library with a set of functions, how do i make it so that when i am using these functions in a separate script, something similar to the below yellow box appears that provides extra context and information.
[image]

I know that by default this yellow box will show the required parameters for the specific function, however in the past i have seen these boxes contain extra added information and comments about the parameters that couldnt possibly just be added automatically by the IDE, so how do i go about adding this information to my functions, and what is the proper name for these comments?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to document a method with parameter(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195455/how-to-document-a-method-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can do things like this by just defining your params in your function, you can improve this with type hinting. You can also use a DOCstring at the start of your function to give info. however some of this may be dependent on the IDE you use. Example code

```py
def my_func(param1: str, param2: int, some_flag=True) -> None:
    """This is a simple function to utilise IDE tooltips and hints"""
    return None


my_func("test", 1)
```

[image]

[image]