# Should I write dict or {} in Python when constructing a dictionary with string keys?

Tags: python, coding-style

This is just a trivial question of what convention you suggest. Recently, I have seen many examples of people writing `dict(key1=val1, key2=val2)` instead of what I think is the more idiomatic `{"key1": val1, "key2": val2}`. I think the reason is to avoid using `""` for the keys, but I am not sure. Perhaps the `dict()`-syntax looks closer to other languages?

Comment: ain't python great .. there's more than one obvious way to do it

Comment: An obvious advantage of the `{}` version is that if you later decide to use some non-string keys you don't have to rewrite the whole line.

Comment: To be on the safe side you could always combine the two - a sort of 'belt and braces' approach: ``kwargs={"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}; d = dict(**kwargs)``.

Comment: @Blair: that's not safe, that's just wasteful.

Comment: @larsmans - its safe in the sense you are guaranteed to have used the idiomatic version ;). That suggestion was made with tongue firmly in cheek.

Comment: @wim That contradict the Zen of Python [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @Dikei So the python creators have violated the Zen of Python by making `dict` accept keyword arguments?

Comment: Well, the Zen of Python is a guideline, not a requirement :)

Comment: take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388187/what-is-the-proper-way-to-format-a-multi-line-dict-in-python/6389593#6389593

Comment: @Blair: ok, time to exercise my irony detection lobe again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to go against the flow here:

Use the `dict()` method if it suits you, but keep the limitations outlined in other answers in mind. There are some advantages to this method:

- It looks less cluttered in some circumstances
- It's 3 characters less per key-value pair
- On keyboard layouts where `{` and `}` are awkward to type (AltGr-7 and AltGr-0 here) it's faster to type out

Comment: There is obviously not a correct answer here, but I like yours best. I think SO has an unfortunate tendency to automatically vote up comments by users with the highest reputation.

Answer (score 8):

`{"key1": val1, "key2": val2}` is more idiomatic; I hardly ever encounter `dict` with keyword arguments and I've certainly never been tempted to write it. It's also more general, because keyword arguments have to be Python identifiers:

```
>>> {"foo bar": 1}
{'foo bar': 1}
>>> dict(foo bar=1)
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     dict(foo bar=1)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> dict("foo bar"=1)
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression (<ipython console>, line 1)
```

Comment: There are cases when Python uses words where other languages use punctuations. It produces less line noise. `dict()` might be more readable when it can be used (Obviously it can't be used if keys are not valid Python identifiers; in that case there is no question what to use).

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, use {}, keep code simple & type less is always my target

Comment: Well, here you can't have both. For two or more keys, the `dict()` method will mean less typing: two quotes and one space character less per key-value pair, if you follow PEP8 recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

There is some ambiguity with the braces { }.  Consider:

```
>>> x = {'one','two','three'}
>>> type(x)
<type 'set'>
>>> x = {}
>>> type(x)
<type 'dict'>
```

Whereas there is no ambiguity with using `set()` or `dict()`.

Comment: Good point but this is very minor when you consider the other points being made.