# Can I do a variable assignment and list insertion at the same time in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Context: I'd like to specify the names of a bunch of directories that I want my script to make. I'd like to declare these path names as variables and add them to a list, which I will iterate over to make the directories. Python 2.7.5.

I'm trying the following:

```
dir_list = [
(dir_1 = "<path_to_dir_1>")
(dir_2 = "<path_to_dir_2>")
]
```

And I get:

```
    (dir_1 = "<path_to_dir_1>"),
           ^           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I do:

```
dir_1 = "<path_to_dir_1>"
dir_2 = "<path_to_dir_2>"
dir_list = [dir_1, dir_2]
print dir_list
```

It works fine without an error.

I have searched and did not find an answer to this question, though I did find an answer to how to format multi-line dictionaries in Python: [What is the proper way to format a multi-line dict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388187/what-is-the-proper-way-to-format-a-multi-line-dict-in-python)

And the PEP8 style-guide offers guidance on how to format multi-line lists as well: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

However, I have not found an answer to whether I can collapse variable assignment and list inclusion into one step.

Comment: The list eliminates all need for the variables. Just use the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is No.  In Python 2.7, an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt) is a statement, so cannot be included in the context of a [list element](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target_list).  There may be a way to unpack a list into other variables, but not exactly as you state.  I look forward to the real Python experts weighing in :) .

Answer (score 1):

No. An assignment is not an expression (it doesn't evaluate to anything), so you cannot simultaneously assign to a variable *and* insert into a list.

Answer (score 1):

This is just not possible since what you are trying to do will be considered as an `assignment`:

```
Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.
```

from [5.14 Evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

so that every expression that is at the right of the assignment operand `=` will be evaluated before the left side and yours is formally a `syntax error`.

Answer (score 1):

Without full context of your situation, my preference is to keep it simple.

```
dir_1 = '<path_to_dir_1>'
dir_2 = '<path_to_dir_2>'
dir_list = [dir_1, dir_2]
print dir_list
```

However, as you've explicitly rejected this, my next choice is a dict

```
dir_dict = dict(
    dir_1='<path_to_dir_1>',
    dir_2='<path_to_dir_2>',
)
print dir_dict.values()
```

You seem not to like dicts either, so I will offer this monstrosity that abuses `locals()`, but I strongly advise against it.

```
dir_1 = '<path_to_dir_1>'
dir_2 = '<path_to_dir_2>'
dir_list = [path for name, path in locals().items() if name.startswith('dir_')]
print dir_list
```

Python is all about simplicity (and dictionaries) so I'd say embrace them.

One last alternative: you could create a dictionary subclass that allows attribute access of its keys. This means fewer quotes around path names.

```
class PathCollection(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(PathCollection, self).__init__(*args, *kwds)
        self.__dict__ = self

paths = PathCollection()
paths.dir_1 = '<path_to_dir_1>'
paths.dir_2 = os.path.join(paths.dir_1, '<relative_to_path_dir_2>')
print paths.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can deal it with dict:

```
dir_list = [
    {"dir_1" : "<path_to_dir_1>",
     "dir_2" : "<path_to_dir_2>"}
]
```

and if it's must to use list, you can't declare a variable like you did, you can only do this:

```
dir_list = ["<path_to_dir_1>", "<path_to_dir_2>"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing, but I don't think you need a dict, you just need a list of paths, which goes like this:

```
dir_list = ['c:/users/me/hi', 'c:/users/you/hi', ...]
```

Then you can iterate over it:

```
for path in dir_list:
    os.mkdir(path) #or os.mkdirs(path), check the usage
```

If you want to name each path, you can use a dict however:

```
dir_dict = {'me': 'c:/users/me/hi', 'you': 'c:/users/you/hi'...}
```

Which you can then iterate through by the key names:

```
for name in dir_dict.keys():
    path = dir_dict[name]
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Then you could incorporate those names in somehow.

Edit: If you wanted to, for example, build from a source like this:

```
source = [('name', 'c:/path/%s'), ('you', 'c:/otherpath/%s'), ('him', 'c:/yetanotherpath/%s')]

dir_paths = dict()
for elem in source:
    dir_paths[elem[0]] = elem[1] % (elem[0])

dir_paths
> {'him': 'c:/yetanotherpath/him',
   'name': 'c:/path/name',
   'you': 'c:/otherpath/you'}
```

I'm not clear on how you're building your list of paths and names - is there some process, or are you just typing a bunch in?

Comment: You're right, I don't need a dict - which is why I'm not making one. I do want the directories to have variable names - what if someone comes along later and wants to change the on-disk location of a directory that still logically points to the same resource? Variable name maintains the logical connection while permitting assignment of a new physical location. The benefit is separation of physical and logical layers.

Comment: If you want to name the paths for future reference, a dictionary is what you need.  Your first bit of code with the syntax error looks exactly like creating a dictionary.  Or if the order matters for you the way a list maintains, you can use an ordereddict from collections.

Comment: If I use a dict can I do the assignment at the same time as insertion into the dict?

So:

dir_dict = {'me': 'c:/user/me', 'my stuff': '%s' %(me + '/mystuff') }

'my stuff' should evaluate to: 'c:/user/me/mystuff'

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'll add something to my answer.

Comment: Typing a bunch in :(
EDIT: like this - dir_1 = "/dir1", dir_2 = dir_1 + "/dir2", etc. there are lots of these, they are not all linear (otherwise i'd do one os.makedirs and be done with it) etc.